# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In c#, I am trying to compare the current day with the day the user has chosen from the checkboxes via the website. CDays contains the list Mon-Fri (Name) and Selected will be true if the user has checked the current days' checkbox. For example today is Friday, if the user has checkboxed Friday on the website return true.

I am running into **Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'string'** and I'm not sure how to convert DateTime to a string

```
 public List<CDay> days { get; set; }
    public CDay()
    {
     Name = string.Empty; // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
     Selected = false; //will be true if user has selected this checkbox
    }
```

my logic:

```
private bool currentDayOfTheWeek (DateTime now, List <CDay> days)
        {
          now = DateTime.Now;
        
          for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
          {

            if ( days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && now == days[i].Name) 
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
              }
            return false;
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == days[i].Name`

Comment: Hm, well I need to use the (DateTime now) condition thats in my currentDayOfTheWeek method

Comment: then use now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == days[i].Name

Comment: by the way you are passing DateTime now as parameter , but inside method you are overriding the value with now = DateTime.Now

Comment: Ahh I see. Is using DateTime as a parameter the wrong logic?

Comment: if you are actually passing value in that parameter to this method then no need to override it with DateTime.Now, but if no value is passed then use local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option DayOfTheWeek from 'now' object...

Something like this:

```
if (now.DayOfWeek == days[i].Name){
//code
}
```

Comment: The same error occurs for this code

Comment: Use .ToString() after DayOfWeek

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use this one now.DayOfWeek.ToString() == days[i].Name